# Java error "Undefined name"

Tags: java

I've tried fixing this I just cant seem to find a solution to this problem. The code is meant to print the prime numbers in a range, but it just returns the error

> Static Error: Undefined name 'PrimeNumbers

Would anyone please be able to help me ?

This is my code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeNumbers { 

    private List<Integer> listOfPrimeNumbers;  //add a member variable for the ArrayList
    public static void main(String args []){    
      PrimeNumbers primeNumberList = new PrimeNumbers(50);
      primeNumberList.print();  //use our new print method
    }

public PrimeNumbers (int initialCapacity) {
    listOfPrimeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(initialCapacity/2);  //initialCapacity/2 is an easy (if not tight) upper bound
    long numberOfPrimes = 0; //Initialises variable numberOfPrimes to 0
    int start = 2;
    boolean[] isPrimeNumber = new boolean[initialCapacity + 1];

    for (int i=0;i==initialCapacity;i++) {//setting all values in array of booleans to true
    isPrimeNumber[i] = true;
    }
     while (start != initialCapacity)
        {
          if (isPrimeNumber[start])
          {
            listOfPrimeNumbers.add(start);
            //add to array list
            numberOfPrimes++;
            for (int i = start; start < initialCapacity; i+=start)
            {
              isPrimeNumber[i] = false;
            }
          }
          start++;
        }
    }

  public void print() {
    int i = 1; 
    for (Integer nextPrime:listOfPrimeNumbers) {
      System.out.println("the " + i + "th prime is: " + nextPrime);
      i++;
    }
  }
 //or just System.out.println(listOfPrimeNumbers);, letting ArrayList's toString do the work.  i think it will be in [a,b,c,..,z] format

 public List getPrimes() {
   return listOfPrimeNumbers;
 } //a simple getter isnt a bad idea either, even though we arent using it yet
}
```

Comment: Yes, how do you run it? The code itself is fine, it compiles and executes on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, you have you code organized like this

```
./project
   PrimeNumbers.java
   PrimeNumbers.class
```

then you `cd` to `./project` and type

```
java PrimeNumbers
```

**Note** - this only works because you didn't declare a package (iaw: you class is *in the default package*). Usually you have a package declaration and then it looks a bit different.

---

**Bonus**

The getter is a good idea, but you should think twice before returning a collection, because this way, you grant the receiver full access to your (internal?) datastructure and he can alter the values of that collection. And you shouldn't declare it with the *raw type*. Here's a better way to implement it:

```
public List<Integer> getPrimes() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(listOfPrimeNumbers);
}
```

Now the receiver knows that he get's a list of `Integer` values and can't modify the result.